# USERELATIONSHIP in a measure with text column

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

CONTEXT:

I want to monitor payment transactions for money laundering, where payments cross multiple borders. There are a max of 6 countries shown per transaction. For each of these countries, I need to know a risk level.

I have 2 tables:

1. Transaction data (where there are many transactions from same country)
2. Country Risk (containing each country once, with an added risk classification. There are 100+ countries, and only 6 different Risk levels).

Problem:

I would like to look up the Risk Classification per country in Transaction Data. The problem is, there are 6 countries per transaction in Transaction Data. So I have to link Transaction data to Country Risk 6 times. Only 1 relationship can be active, of course.

So I tried writing the following measure:

```
CALCULATE(   
VALUES('Country Risk'[Risk classification]);  
USERELATIONSHIP('Transaction Data'[Country 2];'Country Risk'[Country Code]))
```

I get an error though when using the measure in a graph where I listed the countries from Transaction Data (where every country is mentioned in multiple rows) and I wanted to see the related risk categories:

**A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected**

What am I doing wrong?

Made similar test data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_kJW-BpbrwCsbSpxdo7AJ3IzPy2oLWFJ/view?usp=sharing

**Needed:**

1. for every C (C1-C6) column I need to add the risk category.
2. For every C column I need to make a pie chart showing the number of transactions per risk category for that C column
3. Pie charts should filter the transaction oevrview: (

Comment: To increase the chance of receiving high quality answers, I would suggest you to edit your question to the template: 1) Context, 2) Problem, 3) Simple but representative example with a table, 4) Expected solution based on the example proposed in section (3).

Comment: Looks like a many to many relationship, post more information. But it would be better if you create a bridge table between transactions and risk levels.

Comment: Country country is already a bridge in a way, since every country is there only once.  I don't understand how formatting works on this site, so it;s hard to post an example..

Comment: added picture, hope this helps?

Comment: @Seymour I added a very fake data sample, maybe this will help

Comment: @mxix  I added a very fake data sample, maybe this will help

Comment: Include images who the model or a simplified one. Sample Data and expected outcome. So we can understand the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taked a PBI consultant about this, there is no way to get this issue solved the way I want it to (to have multiple relationships between 2 tables all acting as if they were active relationships at same time).

the only way of getting it done would be:
1. write measures (but that doesn't allow cross filtering between pie chart and table below)
2. unpivot the country columns (but that wouldn't allow to have 6 columns with risk category in table)
3. have 6 dimension tables (this solves the issue, because it allows both cross filtering between piechart and other piecharts & table. and it would allow to have 6 columns for separate risks in the table visual)

thanks for trying to help guys!

Comment: Try to re-think the problem. Do you really need this very complex implementation or could you accept an alternative solution? For example, split in two pages or use more than one visualization etc